# UIImageView Increase Brightness in specific area

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiimageview, uiimage

How can I increase brightness in specific area of a UIImageView,
For ex:I have an imageview with image.I want to increase the brightness of image in specific elliptical area of that image.
I know how to increase the brightness of whole image , But dont know for specific elliptical area.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a black `UIView` with a specific alpha apply on it (this will control how dark you want your view) and attach a mask layer to this view that has an ellipse. For the part of your view that is masked it will be brighter.

You need to import the `Quartzcore` framework when you are working with layer/mask. The mask is a property of your view layer (`[yourView layer].mask`).

Comment: Let me check this , Mean while ,Can you please post some lines of code if possible ?

Comment: This one not work well for me, but the idea is good , What is did is took 2 images , one is original and second is brightened , I crop the brightened image in elliptical shape and just add subview above the original image.So the result will look like some part of original image is brightened ..thank you Tiguero